# Why doesn't LaTeX allow me to import my .eps file when I compile it?

Tags: graphics, errors, eps

Everything works perfectly except until the error below. I'm slightly new at LaTeX and perhaps I'm missing a package, but I already have the `graphicx` package.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .eps.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.24 \includegraphics[width=2.6in]{02_1.eps}

?
```

Comment: Try latex instead of pdflatex. ...Rolf

Answer (score 12):

With a sufficiently new installation, pdfLaTeX will auto-convert `.eps` files to `.pdf` format for inclusion. However, this relies on you not giving the file extension as part of the name

```
\includegraphics[width=2.6in]{02_1} % No '.eps'
```

(From comments, I see you have MiKTeX 2.9, and this MiKTeX should do the auto-conversion.)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use `pdflatex`, you can't directly compile with `eps` files. So you can convert them beforehand or convert them "on-the-fly" with the package [epstopdf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg).

Or you could just use `latex`, which outputs `DVI`, not `PDF`, but you can use `eps` files directly.

Comment: I see that it's creating DVI file. I'm using MikTex 2.9 if this makes a difference. At the end I would like it to be in PDFs and so far whenever I make worksheets they've always been outputted as both DVI and PDF. But now that I'm using eps it's not working like when I was using jpg.

Comment: I have the esptopdf package installed already but it's still not working.

Comment: @econ `\write18` must be enabled. Please read section **1.2 Requirements** of the package documentation.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina With a sufficiently new installation, `epstopdf` is called automatically by `graphics` using 'restricted shell escape', so `\write18` does _not_ need to be enabled.

Comment: @econ: if you want to produce pdf output, (imo) you're best converting the .eps figures to .pdf; that way, one source of doubt is eliminated.  if (as you say) you're producing dvi _and_ pdf from a standard run, we need more details, like a sample that processes to produce the error, and also some details of _how_ you run (pdf)latex -- is it from one of the ide thingies, by any chance? -- if so, which one?

Comment: Might a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) be of use here? That is, if you are using the `epstopdf` package and it's _still_ not working.

Answer (score 3):

`epstopdf` package will probably solve this problem:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

Comment: "probably" sounds conditional. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I ve both graphicx and epstopdf. Still Arxiv says file not found. Any sol?