# Insert and compile EPS

Tags: floats, texmaker, eps

I want to upload an .eps figure in my latex, i read this 
thread 
[Why doesn't LaTeX allow me to import my .eps file when I compile it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69355/why-doesnt-latex-allow-me-to-import-my-eps-file-when-i-compile-it)

Although i got confused, is TexMaker able to convert .eps fully or is there a package which i should use?

```
\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 

\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{figure}[H]\label{East Scotland}
%\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{figures/2.jpg}
\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{figures/boundaries_1h.eps}
\caption{Mesh and coordinates for North Sea, depth is in meters(m) }
\end{figure}
\end{flushleft}


\end{document}
```

thank you

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg

Comment: @Sverre It is not like the usual packages which you download in the file and compile
.It warns me that epstopdf.sty Shell escape feature is not enabled , what does that mean?

Comment: It means that  `pdflatex`  must be launched with the `--shell-escape` switch (from TeXmaker Option -> Configure). It enables pdflatex to interrupt compilation to let an external application be launched. Alternatively, you could do the conversion to pdf by hand, using `epspdf` or `epspdf-extra` if you're under Windows: it has a gui interface. The former is included in TeX Live (not in MiKTeX). You can take a look at a presentation, and download from here: ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/epspdf.html, ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/epspdf-extra.html.

Comment: It might be outdated, but there is still `latex` to compile `*.tex` files with `.eps` files included